# Create Multiple Connections from bat file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, batch-file, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

What I'm trying to do is to simulate a 50-60 connections querying the same statement.
I created a batch file and can successfully call the .sql file within (sqlcmd).
The next step would be to adjust the batch file so that it creates 50 separate connections. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you (1) don't want to have the same line 50 times in your batch and (2) want that your commands to be executed "at once" instead of one after the other.

(1) Use a for loop!

(2) Use START:
If you just execute your sqlcmd command 50 times the cmd will always wait for the last call to finish. You can avoid this by using START. In this case the command is being executed but the cmd doesn't wait for it to finish.

So your code might look something like this:

```
FOR /L %%x in (1, 1, 50) DO (
    START sqlcmd.exe /param1 /param2 ...
)
```

You might want to log your output or somehow differ between your sqlcmd calls. To do so you can use %%x (e.g. to create log files):

```
FOR /L %%x in (1, 1, 50) DO (
    START sqlcmd.exe /param1 /param2 ... >> log%%x.txt
)
```

Comment: Man. Thank you very much. It worked but not to a complete degree. I need the connection to be kept open. i.e If there are 50 connections, I have to keep each of them in an infinite loop sending the .sql statement to the server. Kind of load testing while I collect performance data. Thank you.